# How to rollback the committed changes in the Vector Layer in qgis

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2

I selected few features in the vector layer and updated the field. But I want to rollback the changes committed to the vector layer. How can I do that in QGIS?

I have used the following coed:

`layer.rollBack()`

But it is of no use. How can I rollback the committed changes in the vector layer in QGIS?

Comment: "Commit" means just that. The way to a point in time before commit involves a restore from a previous backup.

Comment: Are you using Vector layer from raw .shp file or any database..please specify.

Comment: Have you seen this post, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35653/what-is-the-proper-way-to-do-an-automatic-rollback-of-a-vector-layer-edit

Answer (score 3):

You could try using one of those interface rollback actions:

```
qgis.utils.iface.actionRollbackEdits().trigger()
qgis.utils.iface.actionRollbackAllEdits().trigger()
```

First is for current layer and second is for all layers.

However, those rollback actions only work with undo from QGIS. If you commit changes you cannot rollback.

Comment: those rollback actions works with undo from Qgis. If you commit changes you cannot rollback.